# Download attachments from multiple outlook emails c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to download the attachments from multiple emails in Outlook with the same subject line using C#.  Using the code below I can download and save the first email but not subsequent emails.  Any help would be appreciated.

```cs
try
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application MyApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace MailNS = MyApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder MyInbox = null;

    MyInbox = MailNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem InboxMailItem = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems = MyInbox.Items;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailitem = MyApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

    string Query = "[Subject] = 'Entitlement Custodian'";

    InboxMailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oItems.Find(Query);

    while (InboxMailItem != null)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachments attachments = InboxMailItem.Attachments;
        if (attachments != null && attachments.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= attachments.Count; i++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attachment = attachments[i];

                string filename = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\donald.dougherty\Desktop\Custodians", attachment.FileName);
                attachment.SaveAsFile(filename);

                lbAttachments.Items.Add(filename);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    MyApp = null;
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{

}
```

Thanks in advance,
Don

Comment: You forgot to call `InboxMailItem = oItems.FindNext()` in loop, also remove `break`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  Have a nice day.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, we have an inbox for the IT department that we want the users to put these emails in instead of my inbox.  Can I read emails from that inbox through C#?

Comment: Sorry, never tried Outlook API, just read documentation for your particular case.

Comment: OK, thank you.  Have a nice day.